# GNU Prolog - Build up a list in a loop

Tags: list, prolog

I need to build a new list with a "loop". Basically i can't use recursion explicitly, so i am using append to go through lists of list.

I can get the element. Problem is i need to check this element and if something is true it returns another element i need to put back into the list. It does check correctly and it changes correctly.

Problem i am having is how do i create a completely new list.

So, if i had

```
[[1,1,1],[2,6,2],[3,3,3]]
```

I go through each element. say i get to the 6 and it changes. So i need to create a new list like so,

```
[[1,1,1],[2,10,2],[3,3,3]].
```

Right now my main problem is just creating each row. If i can create each row, i will be able to create a list of lists.

So to break this down a little more, lets just worry about [1,1,1].

I go through each element while appending the new element to a newlist. the new list is now [1,1,1]

I have this:

```
set(Row,Col,Bin,TheEntry,Bout) :- 
 append(ListLeft, [R|_], Bin),
  append(ListLeft2, [C|_], R),
   length(ListLeft, LenR),
   length(ListLeft2,LenC),
   CurrRow is LenR + 1,
   CurrCol is LenC + 1,
   getChar(C, Row, Col, CurrRow, CurrCol,TheEntry, NewC),
            appendhere?.
```

I need to create a new list there with the character returned from NewC. Not sure how to do this.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use recursion ? What you want to do can be easily done using recursion.

Comment: I know it can, but its homework. My teacher doesn't want us to use recursion. He wants us to use backtracking, although we can use append.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `assert`/`retract`? http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node94.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an idea about how to use `append/3` to extract an item from a list of lists, consider the following predicate called `replace/2`:

```
replace(In, Out) :-
    append(LL, [L|RL], In), 
    append(LE, [E|RE], L),
    replaceElement(E, NewE), !,
    append(LE, [NewE|RE], NewL),
    append(LL, [NewL|RL], Out).
replace(In, In).
```

This *non-recursive* predicate takes, as `In`put, a list of lists, and backtracks to find an element `E` within an inner list `L` that can be replaced via `replaceElement/2`; if so, it is replaced by constructing the inner list first (`NewL`), then uses this new list in the construction of the new outer list (`Out`), as the result.

**Note** that this simply serves to demonstrate how to use `append/3` to break apart a list of lists to retrieve individual elements as you need *via backtracking, and not recursion, as requested*. Once an element `E` is found to be replaceable by `NewE` via `replaceElement/3`, it is used in the construction of the list again using `append/3` as shown.

Also note that this *suggestion* (which is intended to help you, not be your final answer) also happens to replace only a single element within an inner list, if any at all. If you want to do multiple replacements of the input list in a single call to `replace/2` or similar *using this technique*, then you will almost certainly need a recursive definition, or the ability to use the global database via `assert`. I'm happy to be corrected if someone else can provide a definition as a counterexample.

With this example predicate `replace/2`, together with, say, the following fact:

```
replaceElement(6, 10).
```

Executing the following gives us your required behaviour:

```
1 ?- replace([[1,1,1],[2,6,2],[3,3,3]], Out).
Out = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 10, 2], [3, 3, 3]] ;
false.
```

If you cannot use cut (`!`), it is fine to omit it, but note that the second clause `replace(In, In)` will cause all calls to `replace/2` to backtrack at least once to give you the input list back. If this behaviour is undesirable, omitting this second clause will cause `replace/2` to fail outright if there is no replacement to be made.

Comment: interesting. Ill check this out in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use recursion and have to do it with backtracking you should do something like this:
Assume Bin is a list of lists (each item is a full row)
~ Split input Bin in three parts (a list of 'left' rows, a Row, and a list of remaining rows). This can be done using append/3 with something like append(Left, [Item|Rest], Rows)
~ Now obtain the length of the 'left' rows
~ Test the length using 'is' operator to check wether the left list has Row - 1 items
~ Do the same but now with the Item, i.e. split it in three parts (LeftColums, ColumItem and Rest)
~ Test now the length against the required Column
~ Now you have the Item to change so all you need to do is rebuild a list using two appends (one to rebuild the chosen row and another to rebuild the output list).

So from your code you wouldn't use unnamed variables (_). Instead of that you have to use a named variable to be able to rebuild the new list with the item changed.